# Find-Package | Install-Package (local feed)

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget

I have setup a local feed and I want to install packages from it, from the command line

```
Find-Package -Name "*hukarz*" -Source C:\feed | Install-Package
```

I get this error:

```
Install-Package : Unable to resolve package reference ''.
At line:1 char:47
+ Find-Package -Name "*core*" -Source C:\feed | Install-Package
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($UGFja2FnZSBzb3...4x\QzpcZmVlZA==:String) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToResolvePackage,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

Should this command be able to install packages from a local feed?

The feed is also correctly registered

```
dotnet nuget list source
..
4.  Package source 1 [Enabled]
      c:\feed
```

Installing from inside of Visual Studio works fine.

Comment: Is the project using `PackageReference`, or `packages.config`?  Is the `c:\feed` source defined in a `nuget.config`? (can you select it from the package source drop-down menu, or if you go into package source settings, in VS options, is it listed?).  Using `-Source` to provide a URL or path that NuGet doesn't otherwise know about only works for `packages.config`, not `PackageReference`.

Comment: yes, I've added that to the question.